# How to set Cache-Control in Java when inserting file to GS bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-api-java-client

I am uploading my files to Google Cloud Storage through the Java API via a `Storage.Objects.Insert` instance.

Everything works fine, I can set my ACL, etc. but I am not sure how I can set metadata on the file I am uploading. Mainly, I want to extend the "Cache-Control" header.

There is a `set` method on the `Insert` object, but it is not documented and I am not sure what it is doing.

I am looking for a Java equivalent to:

```
gsutil setmeta -h "Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000" gs://{my_bucket}/{my_file}
```

And I hope there is a way to set this header when I upload the file through the Insert object.

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [sample code here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert) for inserting an object using the Java API. Note that it supplies a [StorageObject](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/storage/model/StorageObject.html) class, which has a [setCacheControl](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/storage/model/StorageObject.html#setCacheControl(java.lang.String)) header you can use.

Comment: I was unable to follow your link and find the sample described; perhaps it has moved.  That is the problem with link-only answers

Comment: I see that this is a rather old Q&A.  Perhaps there is updated google doc to cover this case now?