# How to set cache-control in google storage from Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I *believe* that am seeing some cases on Google Storage, where listing a folder after deleting all blobs within the folder still shows that they exist, even after waiting several seconds.  This happens quite rarely so it has been hard to pin down.  While I do not know the root cause, I am thinking that it is possible for caching to cause this effect, especially since my google storage tests are running remotely, not in a GCP VM.

Thus I hope that setting the Cache-control metadata to "no-cache" will fix the problem.  But I cannot find how to do this from the Java SDK client.  One SO answer has link-only solution, which is broken: [How to set Cache-Control in Java when inserting file to GS bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27336763/how-to-set-cache-control-in-java-when-inserting-file-to-gs-bucket)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "control-cache" is simply a [metadata on the object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#cache-control). In Java, you have that sample in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-set-metadata#storage_set_metadata-java)

Comment: Thanks... but I think for this to work reliably I need to set the meta-data when the object is created?  How is that done?

Comment: Do you create the object in your Java code? If so, you can add that piece of code to update the metadata. If not, you can catch the event of new object creation on the bucket and add a function on that event which add the cache control on the file. Else, explain more your context/blockers

Comment: Thanks Guillaume.  Does my theory sound plausible, as far as the out-of-date listing issue observed?  I really just want to fix that issue, and this is the only thing I could think of.  Could there be other reasons why, after deleting blobs, they still appear in the listing?  It is such a rare occurrence that it is hard to test.

Comment: You have the definition of the consistency [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency). It's possible there is cache in the APIs but normally the deletion process is strongly consistent.

Comment: The only part that worries me is this statement: "Cached objects that are publicly readable might not exhibit strong consistency".  Does this only apply to objects that are truly public, no credentials required to read them?

Comment: Not clear. I would like to say yes, but I'm not sure